# 2nd order ODE function not callable Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I am new to Python programming and I have been struggling with the sympy library for 2 days now.

I have been browsing on stackoverflow but I could not find answers.

I want to solve a second order differential equation with its initial conditions.

```
import sympy as sp 
import numpy as np
import math

#setting parameters 

I1 = 0.0004 #m4
E = math.pow(40,9) #Pa
RA = 875 #N
l1 = 4 #m
r = E*I1

#declaration of symbolique variable and function 

x = sp.symbols('x') 
y1 = sp.Function('y1')

#equation and solving

diffeq1 = sp.Eq(sp.diff(y1(x),x,2), (RA*x)/r)

y1_sol = sp.dsolve(diffeq1, y1(x))

print('y1_sol =', y1_sol)
```

I have 2 problems :

1. the sympy.Function is said to be not callable even if the program works and gives me the right result.
2. Despite all syntaxes for inital conditions I have tried so far, none of them worked (In my opinion it might be linked with the first problem).
   Could you send me a clear documentation of how it does work.

Sympy version : 1.6.2

All my grateful thanks to stackoverflow community.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to run this code? This code runs fine on my end

Comment: The code runs fine but I get a warning 'y1 is not callable'. I do not know exactly what does it means.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the wanring you refer to but I am using latest sympy.

The syntax is somewhat odd for ICs for a 2nd order ODE:

```
In [28]: dsolve(diffeq1, y1(x), ics={y1(0): 1, y1(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0): 0})
Out[28]: 
                            3       
           278155008951823⋅x        
y₁(x) = ──────────────────────── + 1
        200000000000000000000000
```

It depends how you defined y1 though e.g.:

```
In [38]: x = Symbol('x')

In [39]: y1 = Function('y1')(x)

In [40]: y1p = y1.diff()

In [41]: y1pp = y1p.diff()

In [42]: eq = Eq(y1pp, RA*x/r)

In [43]: dsolve(eq, y1, ics={y1.subs(x, 0): 1, y1p.subs(x, 0): 0})
Out[44]: 
                            3       
           278155008951823⋅x        
y₁(x) = ──────────────────────── + 1
        200000000000000000000000
```

The ics argument is explained (tersely) in the docs:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#sympy.solvers.ode.dsolve

SymPy's docs can be improved but I recommend looking there first before stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much !